# Colocar footer flutuando sobre outra div

Tags: html, css

Tenho a seguinte estrutura html:

```
<body>
    <div id="gmap"></div>
    <footer>
    //conteudo do footer
    </footer>
</body>
```

Quero colocar a div gmaps ocupando toda a tela e o footer flutuando sobre ela, atualmente esta assim:

[image: Uma div sobre a outra]

Css atual esta:

```
#gmap{
    z-index: 1;
    width:100%;
    height:80vh;
}
footer{
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: Quer o footer por cima do `#gmap`?

Comment: Não sei se é isso, mas seu seletor do css está com o nome errado. Veja: "gmap"

Comment: você vai deixar o gmaps fixo em 100% da tela e o footer sobre ele abaixo, porém fixo também?

Comment: já consegui acrescentando     width:100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; no footer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você deseja que o `footer` esteja por cima da `div` com `id #gmaps`, recomendo usar estas css no `footer`

```
footer{
width:100%;
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Com esse código, poderá colocar o `footer` por cima